# How to solve Linear 4th order PDE

Tags: linear-pde

I would like to know if there is any way to solve (both analytically and numerically) a 4th order PDE of the kind:

$$\phi_{xxxx}-\alpha(t)\ \phi_{xx} +\beta\ \phi\ - \gamma\  \phi_{t}=0$$

in the unknown $\phi(x,t)$;
with suitable boundary conditions and where the apex indicates derivation with respect to $x$ and the subscript $(_{t})$ stands for derivation with respect to time. Is there a numerical procedure more suited for this kind of problem?

Comment: Does the PDE mean $\phi_{xxxx}-\alpha(t)\phi_{xx}+\beta\phi-\gamma\phi_{t}=0$ ?

Comment: yes, it does. I have updated the PDE